# How do I get a jsp to not update the page?

Tags: jsp

I have a jsp calling a second jsp file using the form tag, method="post", with a submit function.
The second jsp is not a page, it's just back end code involving jsp:useBean and some javascript, which runs a report by passing a url to an httpservlet using the window.open method.

Once it runs the second jsp the screen clears out, but the url doesn't change.  If I end the javascript section in the second jsp with window.location.reload() it loads the page defined in the first jsp.  I'm trying to see how to repopulate that screen with the selections made on the controls but is there a way to not clear it in the first place?

Comment: If you want to current page to stay put and call the backend to post or get data, then you need to do the call with clientside Javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Comment: I'm trying to do bean style page (java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/UseBeantoDealwithCheckBox.htm). so I have one jsp with code like document.myform.action="jsp2.jsp"; document.myform.submit(); and <form name="myform" id="myform" method="post" onchange="checkForModifiedFields();">  Then jsp2.jsp has the beans code and some javascript.  After running this the controls on the page, created in jsp1.jsp disappear.  I can call window.location.reload() in jsp2.jsp and it reloads everything defined in jsp1.jsp but without user selected values.